# Как вывести text2 а только потом запустить цикл?

Tags: python, aiogram

```
@dp.message_handler(state=InputWhatever.kolvo)
async def get_number(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):

    await message.answer("text2")

    if message.text.isdigit():
        if int(message.text) > 10:
            await InputWhatever.name_user.set()
            async with state.proxy() as data:
                data["number"] = int(message.text)
                data['user_array'] = []
            await message.answer("Правильно")
        else:
            await message.answer("Введите число больше 0!")
    else:
        await message.answer("Введите кол-во!")
```

У меня как вы видите текст постоянно дублируется, а я хочу чтоб текст вышел один раз в не зависимости от цикла.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался

```
data["number"] = int(message.text)
            data['user_array'] = []
        await message.answer("Правильно")
        await message.answer("text2")
    else:
        await message.answer("Введите число больше 0!")
```

поместил после завершения цикла текст

Comment: Отступы поправьте.